# Differential Equations: Stable, Semi-Stable, and Unstable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to identify the stable, unstable, and semistable critical points for the following differential equation: $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = 4y^2 (4 - y^2)$.

If I understand the definition of stable and unstable critical points, then it seems to me that the semi-stable point is at $y = 0$ since in a neighborhood around $y=0$ we have the slope as positive. It also seems that $y = -2,2$ is a stable critical point since points around its neighborhood are negative for decreasing values and positive for increasing values. So it appears there are no unstable critical points. Am I on the right track here?

I also need to find $k$ for $y(t) \rightarrow k$ given $y(0) = 1.4$ and $k$ for $y(t) \rightarrow k$ given $y(0) = -3.2$.

Any help anyone can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I think you're correct about 0 and 2, but the critical point $y=-2$ seems to be unstable (since $y^{\prime}<0$ to the left and $y^{\prime}>0$ to the right).  You can use your answer to the first part to find the values of k in the second part.

Answer (score 5):

Let me first say that which fixed points are stable/unstable and then the reasons.

From the equation $y'=4y^2(4-y^2)$, the fixed points are $0$, $-2$, and $2$. The first one is inconclusive, it could be stable or unstable depending on where you start your trajectory. $-2$ is unstable and $2$ is stable.

Now, there are two ways to investigate the stability. Since we have a one-dimensional system, the better way would be to draw the graph of

$$f(y)=4y^2(4-y^2)$$

1) On each fixed point, you have two regions (left and right) with your fixed point as the middle point. For example, on the fixed point $y=-2$, the left hand region corresponds to $y<-2$ while the right hand region corresponds to $y>-2$.

2) Let's look at the fixed point $y=-2$. If $f(y)<0$ when $y<-2$, we draw a right-hand-arrow on the left hand region; otherwise draw a left-hand-arrow instead. Repeat the same method on the right hand region.

3) Repeat step (2) for all fixed points.

For our case, you should get a left-hand arrow on $y<-2$ and right-hand arrow on $y>-2$. So, this implies that the fixed point $y=-2$ is unstable. The same method reveals then that $y=2$ is stable. For $y=0$, you would get right-hand arrow on both regions, so this indicates that we have the so called structural stability. For our case, if we start on $y<0$, we will be attracted towards $y=0$; if we start on $y>0$, we will be repelled from $y=0$.

Another method would be to calculate the derivative of $f(y)$ and evaluate it at all the fixed points.

1) If $f'(y)<0$, the fixed point is stable.

2) If $f'(y)>0$, the fixed point is unstable.

3) if $f'(y)=0$, it is inconclusive.